# How to reassign Ctrl+drag in IntelliJ on MacOS?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, macos-mojave

In an Entity Diagram within IntelliJ IDEA, the way to pan around the diagram is to Ctrl+mouse drag. However, that shortcut is conflicting with the MacOS Ctrl+leftclick that is translating to a right-click.

How can we disable the MacOS Ctrl+leftclick mapping or change the IntelliJ mapping for panning in diagrams?

In this article from IntelliJ they mention that the MacOS mapping conflicts with the IntelliJ mapping but there is no suggested fix.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#conflicts

I tried Karabiner and enabled the "Ctrl+Left Click" to "Left Click" rule but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karabiner worked fine... I am using a MacBookPro and have an external mouse and keyboard connected. It turned out that events from the external keyboard were not being processed. Selected it from Karabiner>Devices.

[image]

[image]